# how to select opaque pixels in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

So I'm making a find the object game in flutter and have made an image and separated each item into individual png files. for the sake of positioning each of these items is a 1280x720 file with the object in it and lots of empty space. I want to be able to select the oject without detecting all the empty space around it? MouseRegion is not helping as it detect the image as a whole.

Here is my code

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          height: 720,
          width: 1280,
          child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: [
              const Image(
                image: AssetImage('assets/FullImage.jpg'),
              ),
              MouseRegion(
                opaque: true,
                
                child: const Image(
                  image: AssetImage('assets/Picture_Desc/ball.png')
                  ),
                  onEnter: (event) {
                    print('I have been detected');
                  },
                ),
            ],
            ),
        ),
      )
    );
```

I have been trying to give the image a seperate bounding box but it seems impossible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your solution. Try & test the below-mentioned code. And let me know.

Source code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
            child: Image.asset("assets/full.jpg", fit: BoxFit.cover),
          ),
          Positioned(
            child: ClipOval(
              child: MouseRegion(
                onEnter: print,
                child: Image.asset("assets/ball.png", fit: BoxFit.cover),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Note: Don't forget to replace mine assets path with yours.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with mouse regions and clip ovals as suggested. I made use of 2 mouse regions and a container to act as my clickable area. the solution is the code below

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return MouseRegion(
      opaque: false,
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: [
          Image(
            image: AssetImage(widget._currImg),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: widget._y,
            left: widget._x,
            child:Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                height: widget._height,
                width: widget._width,
                decoration: widget._debugOn? BoxDecoration(
                  //color: Colors.red,
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: widget._boxColor,
                    width: 4,
                    )
                ):
                null,
                child: MouseRegion(
                  opaque: false,
                  onEnter: (event) {
                    setState(() {
                      widget._boxColor = Colors.yellow;
                      widget._currImg = widget._imgs[1];
                    });
                  },
                  onExit: (event) {
                    setState(() {
                      widget._boxColor = Colors.red;
                      widget._currImg = widget._imgs[0];
                    });
                  },
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      if(widget._boxColor == Colors.yellow)
                      {
                        print('I am Clicked');
                      }
                    },
                  ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

the first mouse region give the entire object the ability to have the mouse pass through so that the image does not block the mouseregion. then within the stack i have the base image and a container which i am using as a bounding box for my clickable area. it can be made into a circle by modifying the boxDecoration.